# Is there a way to store value of Matrix in a separate variable, in each loop of while loop so that I get all values of Matrix at the end at once

Tags: matlab

I want to save Matrix(Matrix is name of a matrix) value in a separate variable so that I collected all matrices at the end and then prints it all at once. my current code prints value in each loop while I want to get all values of matrices in the last loop.

```
syms num T1 T2 T3 T4 T3 T6 T7 T8 T9 T10 T5
%Getting data for Robot%
prompt = 'Enter the number of joints in your robot';
X = input(prompt);
num = 0;
while(num<X)
    matrix_number = ['t ',num2str(num),'_', num2str(num+1)];
    link_twist = ['Enter the value of twist(alpha) for the link number',num2str(num+1),' link e.g 10,80 etc'];
    disp(link_twist)
    al = input(prompt);
    link_length = ['Enter the value of offset(d) for the link number',num2str(num+1),' link e.g 1,2,3,4 etc'];
    disp(link_length)
    prompt = ''; 
    d = input(prompt);
    link_offset = ['Enter the value of link length(a) for the link number',num2str(num+1),' link e.g 1,2,3,4 etc'];
    disp(link_offset)
    prompt = ''; 
    a = input(prompt);
    link_theta = ['Enter the value of theta for the link number ',num2str(num+1),' link e.g T1, T2 etc'];
    disp(link_theta)
    prompt = ''; 
    theta = input(prompt);
    Matrix = [cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0 a;
    sind(theta)*cos(al) cosd(theta)*cosd(al) -sind(al) -sind(al)*d; sind(theta)*sind(al) cosd(theta)*sind(al) cosd(al) cosd(al)*d;
    0 0 0 1];
    disp(matrix_number) 
    digits(2)
    printed_matrix = vpa(Matrix);
    pretty(printed_matrix)


    num = num+1;
end
```

Comment: you can see Mathworks documentation for [eval](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) as well as the more elegant method of using the cell array as @ShadoMan posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) data type to store the entire matrix for each run.

Before your while loop you will want to preallocate the array `Carray = cell([X,1])`

Then you can index the array using your `num` value.  You might choose to place this line immediately after you increment `num`

```
...
    num = num+1
    Carray{num} = Matrix
end
```

Now you can access the Matrix generated from each run by passing the index into the `Carray`.

```
Mat3 = Carray{3}
```